# How to handle SQL queries for multiple ajax requests

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html

how should i design php file For each and every selection / on selection change in filters form, it should talk to database, filter rows and display. I tried something like this

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['a']) && empty($_POST['b'])){
$sql = ...;
}

if(!empty($_POST['a']) && !empty($_POST['b'])){
switch($_POST['b']){
//Different sql for different cases. 
} 
?>
```

I think I'll miss many conditions if i do this way. Is there any better way to structure sql queries for different form selections?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT
  *
FROM yourTable WHERE 1
".(empty($_POST['a']) ? "" : "AND city = '".$_POST['a']."'")."
".(empty($_POST['b']) ? "" : "AND fieldb = '".$_POST['b']."'")."
".(empty($_POST['c']) ? "" : "AND fieldc = '".$_POST['c']."'")."
";
```

And so on. Like this you don't have to to seperate cases and rewrite the first part of you sql for every case.

Comment: Why would you "try something like this" and why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear; multiple contidions can set via AJAX call, so the base SQL stays the same, and each contidion is only activated if the POST fields belonging to the condition contains any information.